# CakePHP - Associating models across multiple databases

Tags: php, cakephp, model-associations

I am using two models, each on a different database, but with the same server log in info (host, user and password)

Model **Consumer** (Database A) **HasMany** ConsumerOrder

Model **ConsumerOrder** (Database B) **BelongsTo** Consumer

I've done all associations, but at the moment that I run `$this->ConsumerOrder->fetch('all');`  it is not writing the join, I think it is simply putting a prefix to the name of the database tables, but I don't know how to do it, because it should to change the core.

Any ideas?

**SOLVED**:

I commented the line 1064 in the file "lib / Model / Datasource / DboSource.php"

The line kept CakePHP to generate the joins as the name of the databases are different.

`if ($model->useDbConfig === $linkModel->useDbConfig) {`
`}`

Answer (score -1):

Please check have you import Model in controller or not.
if not so please import model like that..

```
$ConsumerOrder= ClassRegistery::init('ConsumerOrder');
```

After you can write :

```
$variable = $ConsumerOrder->fetch('all');
print_r($variable);
```